# What's wrong with following counting sort program?

Tags: java, counting-sort

Here is my counting sort program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int c[] = new int[100];
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            c[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            c[arr[i]] = c[arr[i]] + 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
        }
        for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
            b[c[arr[i]]] = arr[i];
            c[arr[i]] = c[arr[i]] -1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

**Input:**

> 100
>   63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 86 57 16 83 8 25 81 56 9 53 98 67 99 12 83 89 80 91 39 86 76 85 74 39 25 90 59 10 94 32 44 3 89 30 27 79 46 96 27 32 18 21 92 69 81 40 40 34 68 78 24 87 42 69 23 41 78 22 6 90 99 89 50 30 20 1 43 3 70 95 33 46 44 9 69 48 33 60 65 16 82 67 61 32 21 79 75 75 13 87 70 33

**Expected Output:**

> 1 1 3 3 6 8 9 9 10 12 13 16 16 18 20 21 21 22 23 24 25 25 25 27 27 30 30 32 32 32 33 33 33 34 39 39 40 40 41 42 43 44 44 46 46 48 50 53 56 56 57 59 60 61 63 65 67 67 68 69 69 69 70 70 73 73 74 75 75 76 78 78 79 79 80 81 81 82 83 83 84 85 86 86 87 87 89 89 89 90 90 91 92 94 95 96 98 98 99 99

**Actual Output:**

> 1 1 3 3 6 8 9 9 10 12 13 16 16 18 20 21 21 22 23 24 25 25 25 27 27 30 30 32 32 32 33 33 33 34 39 39 40 40 41 42 43 44 44 46 46 48 50 53 56 56 57 59 60 61 65 67 67 68 69 69 69 70 70 73 73 74 75 75 76 78 78 79 79 80 81 81 82 83 83 84 85 86 86 87 87 89 89 89 90 90 91 92 94 95 96 98 98 99 99

The output that I am getting has one missing digit `63`. I am not able to rectify this issue.

Comment: Can't you use a debugger and figure out? What is the code supposed to do (I mean not sure everyone gets "counting sort")?

Comment: @RC. I tried that, but not able to identify the cause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You iterate from 1 and not 0, so you miss the first number, which is 63

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    c[arr[i]] = c[arr[i]] + 1;
}
```

And in the last loop you break when `i>0`, not `i>=0`